Thermal expansion of solid rod
Let us assume a rod is lying on a rough surface. Now, if temperature is raised it will expand, leading to negative work of friction. But there is no change in kinetic energy of rod, i.e. $\Delta E_{\text{kinetic}} = 0$. How is possible that net work is non zero but change in kinetic energy is zero?
I was thinking of elastic energy that rod possess; but, according to my knowledge, there will be no strain in rod, as it had achieved its natural length, i.e. $\ell(1+\alpha \Delta T)$. So, there will be no elastic energy.

Is it kinetic friction or is it static friction?

The expansion takes place over time. If I focus on a small piece of the rod that isn't at its exact center, and watched it as the rod were heated, I'd see it start to move (thus $\mathrm{d}E_K\neq0$) at least as long as the rod is being heated, no? Keep in mind that heating the rod also takes work.

In what way does heating it. Take work.

The work done by friction damps out the kinetic energy.


How is possible that net work is non zero but change in kinetic energy
is zero?

There is a change in kinetic energy, but not the macroscopic kinetic energy of the center of mass (COM) of the rod. There is an increase in the microscopic (molecular) kinetic energy and temperature of the rod and surface materials at their interface due to the kinetic friction work that opposes and limits the amount of the expansion.
Hope this helps.
